# Will my saved games work with a new copy of Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I played Skyrim on my Playstation 3 last year.  I ended up selling my copy of Skyrim to my friend, but now that they've released DLC for Skyrim on PS3, I'd like to start playing that.

Will this new copy of Skyrim work with my old saved games and characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I have Skyrim installed into my hard drive, bought the DLC from the Playstation Network Store, It works with the install.

It also read my old save perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The DLC would work with your old save games. You don't need anything extra to play the DLC.

You would however, need a new copy of Skyrim to play the DLC.

Answer (score 0):

The save game is in your User account, and **unless** it was deleted for some reason by you *or* the system, it should work.

This is because the discs (BluRays) contain the game but your PS3 contains the **save file**.